# document.getElementById('').style.display='block'; not working in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a function which toggles the content on click.

```
jQuery("#about_temp").click(function($){
    document.getElementById('con_temp').style.display='block';
    document.getElementById('keyc_temp').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('benec_temp').style.display='none';
});
```

Is there any syntax error in this code? It doesn't hide the "con_temp" content. But if I run the same in normal HTML (I mean not in Wordpress), it is working fine.

Comment: if you are using jquery, why are you doing hide show using jquery ? you ca n directly write $("#con_temp").show(); and for all

Comment: $('#con_temp').hide(); hope it will work.

Comment: @JuhiMathur, are you getting any error in the console?

Comment: @SanchitGupta:Console showing dis "TypeError: $ is not a function[Learn More]"

Comment: @VforVendetta hide show also not working :(

Comment: Are you including the required jquery library in the requisite page?

Comment: @JuhiMathur try with `jQuery` instead of `$` if you are using wordpress or use jQuery.noConflict().

Comment: Surely jquery library missing, or not loaded properly, check if alert coming in that

Comment: What says your DevTools? `jQuery is not a function`? Then jquery not loaded, else you should remove unused `$` callback parameter, it refers to element clicked and masks jquery `$` symbol.

Comment: @SanchitGupta worked fine after using jQuery instead of $. Thank you :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try :

```
jQuery(function(){
     jQuery("#about_temp").click(function(){
        jQuery("#con_temp").show();             //  jQuery("#con_temp").css("display","block");
        jQuery("#keyc_temp").hide();            //  jQuery("#keyc_temp").css("display","none");
        jQuery("#benec_temp").hide();           //  jQuery("#benec_temp").css("display","none");
    })
})
```

OR Try with [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) if your page html is generating on the fly or after any event take place

```
jQuery(function(){
    jQuery("body").on("click","#about_temp",function(){
        jQuery("#con_temp").show();              //  jQuery("#con_temp").css("display","block");
        jQuery("#keyc_temp").hide();            //  jQuery("#keyc_temp").css("display","none");
        jQuery("#benec_temp").hide();            //  jQuery("#benec_temp").css("display","none");
    })
})
```

Comment: @JuhiMathur if you are getting ` TypeError: $ is not a function[Learn More] ` replace $ with jQuery or use jQuery.noConflict().

Answer (score 0):

You can use following script

```
jQuery("#about_temp").click(function($){
    jQuery('#con_temp').show();
    jQuery('#keyc_temp, #benec_temp').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your mistake in the code is-- `jQuery("#about_temp").click(function($){...});` -- try changing it to-- `$("#about_temp").click(function() {...})`

```
$("#about_temp").click(function() {
    document.getElementById('con_temp').style.display='block';
    document.getElementById('keyc_temp').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('benec_temp').style.display='none';
});
```

If you are using Jquery it is easier to use the Jquery methods ([hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) and [show](http://api.jquery.com/show)) than Javascript.

Try this ---

```
$("#about_temp").click(function() {
    $('#con_temp').show();
    $('#keyc_temp, #benec_temp').hide();
});
```

Giving a parameter to hide and show like `hide("slow")` or `show("slow")` will give animation effect to the contents.

Comment: @JuhiMathur What is the error or problem you face? Is the click function working correctly? Try checking it using `alert()` function. Is the id of the contents are set correctly?

Comment: no click function is working correctly.have already tried using alert,it is working.only style.display is not working